# Bing Cognitive image search API (v5) returning small number of result

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I'm using Bing Cognitive image search API (v5).
The API always returns a small number of "totalEstimatedMatches".

For example, for the following parameters

```
'imageType':'Photo'
'q': 'cat'
```

The value of "totalEstimatedMatches" is only 104. I believe it should be more.

Comment: Are you using this api: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c? If so, i'm getting a max of 1000 `totalEstimatedMatches`.

Comment: Yes, I am. Today, I'm also getting 1000 "totalEstimatedMatches", though I don't know the differences.  But even 1000 is fewer than expected.  Do you know why the value is only 1000?